# Firebase Analytics JS SDK: Why JS firebase analytics SDK miss events randomly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using this code in a ReactJS app to log events on firebase.

```
if(!firebase.apps.length) firebase.initializeApp(CONSTANTS.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
let analytics = firebase.analytics();
analytics.logEvent(eventName, data);
```

It logs the same event sometimes and misses it altogether at other times. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

you probably can check if your `analytics` is `undefined` in the run-time, your analytics instance might haven't been created when you sending your event. I recommend use this way to make sure it works as you expect

```
firebase.analytics.isSupported().then((isSupported) => {
    if (isSupported) {
      analytics = firebase.analytics();
      analytics.logEvent(...name, ...payload);
    }
})
```